# Roundcube issue Connection to storage server failed

Tags: windows, localhost, imap, webmail, roundcube

I'm using Roundcube mail on Windows 10 with a localhost Wamp. Below are some comands that I found in an answer to the same issue of storage-server-failed but I don't know where to execute these commands or use GUI to remove the devcot files on my Windows 10 PC.

```
cd /home
/etc/init.d/dovecot stop
rm -f */imap/*/*/Maildir/dovecot*
rm -f */imap/*/*/Maildir/.*/dovecot*
rm -f */Maildir/dovecot*
rm -f */Maildir/.*/dovecot*
/etc/init.d/dovecot restart
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was solved by starting Mercury Mail in Xampp.
And creating user in Mercury Mail.

Comment: This is a little confusing. To get roundcube working (ie, an email client), you start Mercury (ie, a mail server), and create a user in Xampp (ie, a php dev environment). In your initial question, the snippets of code relaunch Dovecote, which is an email server. So launching Mercury would provide a server in place of Dovecote. Those lines of code tho are misleading, as they refer to a piece of software which isn't installed here.